# php-cs-fixer [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException] The process has been signaled with signal "6"

Tags: php, laravel, php-cs-fixer

I've installed php-cs-fixer via composer tonight.

But when testing again a php file I'm getting the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
>   The process has been signalled with signal "6".

I've tried removing it and re-installing it to the same effect.

Your help here would be greatly appreciated.

New to laravel PHP programming but enjoying it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out guys/girls.

Was a version issue with php. Not sure how it happened as I'd installed php71 via homebrew but when doing.

php -v it was pointing to the pre-installed version of php on my mac.

PLUS I had a version of mampstack installed on my machine. I removed that.

Reinstalled php71 and did a

php -v

and sure enough, the correct version of php is now running.

The php-cs-fixer is now working as expected.

This was question was my first post to stack overflow :-)

Looking forward to contributing more!

Take care.

Answer (score -1):

You need updates or install some dependencies as follows:

```
$brew install svn
$brew link --overwrite subversion
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - why should updating Subversion solve the given problem? And what makes you think that the OP is using Brew after all?